# How to Detect an SSL Service vs. Non-SSL Service

Tags: python, sockets, security, ssl, openssl

So I have been working on a game, written in Python, that uses networking. The server, as currently written has the ability to run with an SSL context or without, depending on how it is configured by the user on start.

My question is, in Python, what is the simplest way to detect if a host/port you are attempting to connect to is running with SSL or without?

Comment: Always run with SSL is the right answer. If that isn't acceptable then the easiest method is simply try to connect with [SSL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html); if that fails, and you're willing to live with the security implications, then you can next try without SSL. Note that an attacker with a suitable network access can prevent you from successfully connecting with SSL and thereby force you to go unencrypted.

Comment: What is the Error or return that you get from a socket with an SSL context when the server is not using SSL? Is there an exception raised?

Comment: It's best to simply try it yourself, but I get an OSError exception.

Comment: Alright, I'll try testing it out. Now just to verify, this is on the client-side, correct?